# How to split a column of items - which are not in order, into their own columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, survey

So basically, I am looking at survey data, and one of the questions has an answer where people can select multiple options. All these options will now be under one column, but based on the order in which the respondent has selected the options. So basically, when I perform value_counts() on the column, it looks like this:

```
A       10
B       15
C       6
D       19
E       23
A,B     2
A,C     5
A,B,E   7
E,A,C   4
B,C     6
..
```

So now I want to select a combination where respondents have selected at least one of A,B,C or D to this question, but not just A, just B, just C or just D. So in essence, I want the combinations where the selected option is more than one, and the options have at least A/B/C/D. Ex: (A,D,E), (A,B,F), (B,F) and so on.

I have tried splitting this with a simple delimiter and making a column for each option, but the problem is: not all the rows are of same length and also, the order is not always the same and all the first elements go under the first column, which again makes it useless. I have tried manually selecting the options from value counts, like:

```
df = df[(df['variable'] == 'A,D,E') | (df['variable'] == 'B,F')]
```

But I want to be able to automate this, but just don't know how.

I have also tried looking for a sub-string, creating a column, and adding all the numbers - but the issue with this is, it also takes respondents who answered just A, just B, etc. into consideration, which is not something I want.

```
x ='A'
df["A_column"]= df["variable"].str.find(x)
```

Can someone please help me with the logic of this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a dictionary with each string of interest mapped to a character, and transform your `variable` column into the one encoded by characters. Then you can check whether any of the characters corresponding to the strings of interest are present and check whether the length of the transformed column is greater than one.

For example if you have the following `df` and the strings you want to detect are `"str_a", "str_b", "str_c"`:

```
>>> df
                  variable  value
0                    str_a      0
1              str_a,str_b      1
2                    str_b      2
3        str_a,str_b,str_c      3
4                    str_c      4
5  str_a,str_b,str_c,str_d      5
6                    str_e      6
7              str_d,str_e      7
8              str_a,str_d      8
9        str_a,str_d,str_e      9
```

We can make the mapping:

```
variable_map = {'str_a': 'A', 'str_b': 'B', 'str_c': 'C', 'str_d': 'D', 'str_e': 'E'}
```

And transform your variable column:

```
df['variable_encoded'] = df['variable'].replace(variable_map, regex=True)
```

This will give us the following:

```
>>> df
                  variable  value variable_encoded
0                    str_a      0                A
1              str_a,str_b      1              A,B
2                    str_b      2                B
3        str_a,str_b,str_c      3            A,B,C
4                    str_c      4                C
5  str_a,str_b,str_c,str_d      5          A,B,C,D
6                    str_e      6                E
7              str_d,str_e      7              D,E
8              str_a,str_d      8              A,D
9        str_a,str_d,str_e      9            A,D,E
```

Then we can check for the presence of the values corresponding to the keys "str_a", "str_b", "str_c" which would be `"A","B","C"` and that the length of the row is also greater than 1 (to ensure we don't return any rows that only have one of the strings we want).

```
>>> df[(df['variable_encoded'].str.contains("A|B|C")) & (df['variable_encoded'].str.len() > 1)]
```

This gives us the following selection:

```
                  variable  value variable_encoded
1              str_a,str_b      1              A,B
3        str_a,str_b,str_c      3            A,B,C
5  str_a,str_b,str_c,str_d      5          A,B,C,D
8              str_a,str_d      8              A,D
9        str_a,str_d,str_e      9            A,D,E
```

Comment: oops, I have changed the data a bit, to avoid posting the exact data, but the options were more like: I have never seen this before, none of these, seen this on TV, and such instead of A, B or C

Comment: oh yeah, that worked, but I'm afraid df['variable'].str.len() > 1 part would not be so useful in this case

Comment: i will [reluctantly] suggest that you could try mapping each one of your unique strings to a letter. something like `{"i have never seen this before":"A", "none of these":"B", ... }` and then apply my solution, but i admit it's ugly

Comment: oh I get what you are saying, but in this case, since it is not individual strings that I can map to, instead the values of the column look like: {I have never seen this before}, {I have never seen this before, none of these}, {seen this on TV, seen this on Radio}, and such, I might have to manually replace each one of these columns. I appreciate your help, that is definitely useful. I just wanted to point out why it might not be the best way to do that.

Comment: @self.novice_coder could you do something like `df['variable_encoded'] = df.str.replace({"I have never seen this before":"A","none of these":"B"}` and then run that one liner? Let me update my answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

(first I'm creating a dataframe I think is similar to yours)

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'answer': 'A,B,C'}, {'answer': 'A,D'}, {'answer': 'B,C,D'}, {'answer': 'D,E'}, {'answer': 'E'}, {'answer': 'B,C'}])
df
  answer
0  A,B,C
1    A,D
2  B,C,D
3    D,E
4      E
5    B,C
```

first step is to turn your csv strings into an explodable column type

```
df2 = df.reset_index().rename(
    columns={'index': 'original_index'}
).pipe(lambda x: x.assign(
    split_answer=x.answer.apply(lambda a: a.split(',')),
    selected=True
))
df2
   original_index answer split_answer  selected
0               0  A,B,C    [A, B, C]      True
1               1    A,D       [A, D]      True
2               2  B,C,D    [B, C, D]      True
3               3    D,E       [D, E]      True
4               4      E          [E]      True
5               5    B,C       [B, C]      True
```

second you can **explode** the new column into multiple rows per answer and **pivot** the options out into columns

```
df2.explode('split_answer').pivot(columns='split_answer', index='original_index', values='selected').fillna(False)
split_answer        A      B      C      D      E
original_index                                   
0                True   True   True  False  False
1                True  False  False   True  False
2               False   True   True   True  False
3               False  False  False   True   True
4               False  False  False  False   True
5               False   True   True  False  False
```

the `selected=True` and `.fillna(False)` is just to get the final result to look nice with booleans